# Meta Keywords does not appear

Tags: magento-1.9, meta-tags, key

The code:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
```

Does not appear on the html (firebug). When I change the name to another it appears. Is the meta keywords correct to be hided ?

Comment: content of meta tag is usually not displayed to users. It is used for seo purpose. you can only view it on the source code.

Comment: So why "<meta name='description'..." is displaying

Comment: that too normally is not displayed.

Comment: are you sure the tag is not broken? or any of the custom work or theme has the feature to show it

Comment: when I change the name="keywords" to name="keywordstest" it appears correctly

Comment: the name "keywords" and "description" are reserved words, if you don't use them, the crawlers won't be able to read the respected tag. they are always looking for these.

Comment: I know. I did just to test

Comment: If you want to show the content of meta keywords and meta description, use some other way, but keep these tags as is.