# meta keyword tag not showing in browser source

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, meta-tags

Fist of all I already look these questions [Meta Keywords does not appear](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/meta-keywords-does-not-appear) and [Magento meta keywords tag not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376973/magento-meta-keywords-tag-not-showing) but my question answer is not listed there.

I am using Magento 1.9 CE in my_theme>default>template>page>html head.phtml when I change keywords name to keywords1 like

```
<meta name="keywords1" content="this keyword, what keyword" />
```

I can see this in browser source but when I back change to keywords like

```
<meta name="keywords" content="this keyword, what keyword" />
```

Magento engine despairs the whole tag.

So there is not the problem if cache etc problem is clear that Magento engine deliberately removing keywords meta tag if anyone knows why it is doing this???

or any solution

Comment: I guess somewhere (local.xml or in category/product layout setting), keywords has been unset.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri can you little elaborate where can I find these settings? sorry  I am new in magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @tahir-yasin mention this is due to Creare SEO, but you don't need to uninstall this extension. Go to your Settings>Configuration> 
In CREARE SEO find General Settings and change "
Disable Meta Keywords Tag and Empty Meta Description Tags?" to "No" your problem will be solved..